# Can you replace a Spring Boot jar while the application is running?

Tags: spring-boot

In our Linux environment applications are restarted periodically (the reasons aren't important here). It would be convenient for us to deploy new versions of an application by copying the application Spring Boot jar on top of the existing (old) jar thereby overwriting it and then simply wait for the application to restart (that is, the JVM running the application to restart).

However, this seems to not work. We get different kinds of errors - sometimes the app just hangs, sometimes we get a ClassNotFoundException. It's as if Spring Boot (or something inside Spring Boot) reopens the jar and expects it to be the same one it was when the application was originally started.

We had a look through Spring's common application properties, but didn't see anything appropriate. Is there a way to make this work? When we were using WAR files we configured the servlet container to unpack the WAR file and run from the unpacked version. Can we do something similar with Spring Boot?

Comment: Could you add more details? By restart you mean JVM is stopped and started? And you overwrite Spring Boot jar while it's running? And do you update just single JAR or also other Spring Boot dependencies? (Or you have bundle)? And what error are you exactly getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the errors you are experiencing can come from multiple sources. Usually replacing the file from a process is not a big problem as the whole file is loaded into memory before execution. Java is a little bit different, because the actual process that is running is the JVM and it only loads the jar file from disk. The JVM loads classes only on demand, this means if there was any class that was not loaded before it will try to load it and most likely fail, if the jar file is different. In the case of spring boot there are also other resources (such as HTML files) inside the jar file that are dynamically loaded.

You mentioned you are using a linux environment. If you can just replace your startup with a script you can just copy the jar and start it from the copied location:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
JAR_NAME="spring-boot.jar"
NEW_JAR_NAME=".$JAR_NAME" # Use an appropriate name here

cp $JAR_NAME $NEW_JAR_NAME
java -jar $NEW_JAR_NAME
rm $NEW_JAR_NAME
```

Now every time you start the application a copy is being made and started from there. You can replace the original jar and on the next restart the new application will load.

You coud also use `rsync` instead of `cp` to avoid copying the same jar twice, if the application is restarted multiple times without changing the jar.

Comment: While I agree with "so-random-dude" below, for constraints defined by Theo, I agree with @Garuno's approach -- use a wrapper script. I would make it more specific -- (i) stop existing app and use "mv" or "ln" instead of "rsync" or "cp" to reduce copy time, maintain consistency, retain old version, (ii) perform "mv" operation only if check-sums of old and new JAR files do not match, (iii) ensure ownership and permissions are correctly set, (iv) set an alert if after restart, application does not come up within a time and (v) purge N-1 JAR files, (vi) add entry into syslog about actions taken

Comment: The wrapper script idea is a good one, thanks for that. It's a good way to go for us. @KishanParekh thanks for your improvements!

Answer (score 0):

> It would be convenient for us to deploy new versions of an application
> by copying the Spring Boot jar on top of the existing (old) jar and
> then simply wait for the application to restart

Why would you do such a thing to yourself?  You are trying solve a usecase that's against best practices, sound like asking for trouble just to avoid an app restart. When you are doing a deployment, you need to make sure the deployment went through, otherwise how will you troubleshoot if something goes wrong in your application, you will have one more variable in hand when you troubleshoot, i,e the uncertainty of current version of the code.

If you are having downtime while deploying (I am assuming thats why you want to limit the restarts), why don't you bring up another instance with the newer version of code and once its healthy shutdown the old one

Comment: I understand your points, they are just not a problem for us in our situation. As mentioned it's for convenience. We can of course find another solution such as the one you mention but that's less convenient. Hence the question.